# gameobjects not rendering on android build in unity 2019.4

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, rendering, game-engine

StackOverflow community. so I made a blender model, imported it to unity, and it renders and works fine in the editor. but for some reason when I build to android, nothing renders, but it all works. even the box colliders work. just the objects not rendering. I tried disabling GPU skinning, but no help at all.

Comment: Can You provide your scene screenshot, your camera and your object settings screeshots?

Comment: everything is default.

Comment: What means "default"? Its hard to help You without any info about GameObjects You are Trying to render

Answer (score 1):

If you are using URP, the answer is here: [solution](https://forum.unity.com/threads/urp-and-webgl.955803/)

On post 5, someone says "Have you added the shaders you're using for these objects to Projects Settings->Graphics->Always Included Shaders?" and this solves the problem.

Comment: nice, but i am not using any render pipeline